# Change minimum order amount for some articels

Tags: orders, cart, ce-1.9.0.1

I have set a minimum order price but I would like some articles to ignore this minimum.

Where do I start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the method `\Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::validateMinimumAmount` and check `$this->getQuote()` for the presence of your special articles. I suggest you add an attribute to such articles which are exempt from the minimum order value to easily identify them.

Another approach - without class overwrites would be the following. But I am not sure if it is worth this effort because it does not seem much cleaner:

1. Hook into some general event (for example `controller_action_predispatch`)
2. check whether one of your items are in the cart
3. temporarily manipulate the store config to set `sales/minimum_order/active` to `false`.

Comment: I extended `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`. Worked fine!