# Bypass Minimum order ammount for downlodable products

Tags: cart, rules

It is possible in a store with 500€ minimum order ammount to set a custom cart rule that allow to bypass the minimum order for a certain type of product or a category?

I tried to set up a shopping cart rule but I can not find the right action.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in shopping cart rules but can be done by overiding `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::validateMinimumAmount` . See [Change minimum order amount for some articels](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37081/change-minimum-order-amount-for-some-articels).